# How to insert new node in existing xml file using TCL(TDom)

Tags: xml, dom, tcl, tdom

I have an existing XML document with more number of nodes and I want to insert a new node, but at a certain position.

The document looks something like:

```
<root>   
    <a>...</a>
    <c>...</c>
    <e>...</e>
</root>
```

... can be considered as xml tags a.../a, c.../c, e.../e. (formatting issue)

The new nodes  should be inserted in alphabetical order in between the nodes, resulting in:

```
<root>
    <>
    new node
    <>
    <>
    new node
    <>
    <>
    <>
    new node
```

How can I use XPath in TCL to find the existing node and insert new node before or after it.

I also want to preserve the order, since the existing tags in XML document are in alphabetical order.

At present I am using tdom package.

Does anyone have an idea on how to insert such a node?

Comment: I've formatted your question so that the content shows up correctly, but it appears to be talking about producing a document that isn't well-formed XML. I don't know the cause of this, but it would help tremendously if you edited your question to add in where you're looking to go. (Indentation by at least 4 spaces makes for a literal section.)

Answer (score 2):

If you've got this in a file, `demo.xml`:

```xml
<root>
    <a>123</a>
    <c>345</c>
    <e>567</e>
</root>
```

And want to go to this (modulo whitespace):

```xml
<root>
    <a>123</a>
    <b>234</b>
    <c>345</c>
    <d>456</d>
    <e>567</e>
</root>
```

Then this is the script to do it:

```
# Read the file into a DOM tree
package require tdom
set filename "demo.xml"
set f [open $filename]
set doc [dom parse [read $f]]
close $f

# Insert the nodes:
set container [$doc selectNodes /root]

set insertPoint [$container selectNodes a]
set toAdd [$doc createElement b]
$toAdd appendChild [$doc createTextNode "234"]
$container insertAfter $insertPoint $toAdd

set insertPoint [$container selectNodes c]
set toAdd [$doc createElement d]
$toAdd appendChild [$doc createTextNode "456"]
$container insertAfter $insertPoint $toAdd

# Write back out
set f [open $filename w]
puts $f [$doc asXML -indent 4]
close $f
```

Comment: And I'd normally wrap up those find-and-insert sequences into a procedure for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the [tutorial](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8984) for tdom on the Tcl wiki answers all of your questions.  There is some additional information on [Xpath](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1957) on the wiki as well.